# Did Luffy know who Sogeking is?

Tags: one-piece

In Ennies Lobby arc when Luffy and his crew members trying to save Robin, Luffy order Sogeking (Usopp) to burn World Government's flag.

How can Luffy know that Sogeking can make something like flamethrower to burn the flag? He only know that Usopp that can burn the flag.

In that time, if I'm not mistaken, Luffy doesn't know about Sogeking's power, he also seems never notice Sogeking is Usopp before and even after the arc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Anime Reference:

As you can watch in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBFMJhbLb2g) scene, it's not that Luffy finds out that Sogeking is actually Usopp. It's just that he introduces himself as:

> **Luffy and Chopper: Sogeking from the Sniper Island?**
>
> **Sogeking (Usopp) : That's right! I'm one of Usopp's close friends. I'm here to help you out on your journey.**

## Manga Reference:

[image]

Hence, when Luffy asks Sogeking to burn down the flag, he asks this to him as a sniper, assuming him to be nearly as good as Usopp.

Comment: oh, forgot about this one, Sogeking told Luffy and Chooper that he is from Snipper Island. *plays Sogeking's Song